# How to run Supabase on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-ecs, supabase

I'm looking for any tutorial or how to guide on deploying Self Hosted Supabase with AWS.
Trying to use the Postgres RDS but it doesn't have pgjwt plugin and we can't install it on manage service like RDS.
Any link will be very helpful, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could run your own customized PosgreSQL database on EC2 instance. There are a decent number of guides available on the net, see for example [this article](https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-provision-a-cheap-postgresql-database-in-aws-ec2-9984ff3ddaea). Don't forget to install etxtra modules (including pgjwt) if they are not included in the PostgreSQL distribution package you used.

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it, `pgjwt` is a pure SQL extension: https://github.com/michelp/pgjwt/issues/4

This means that you can go to the source code, find the SQL and execute them manually on your RDS instance.